# How to add a button to a second drill down View Controller only when called from an alert?

Tags: swift, button

I am new to iOS development, but making progress. Got to a point a bit too much for me to program.

1. I have an alert button (ok) in a first view.
2. Tapping ok, I could call an existing employee table view that also allows searching for employees. Tapping a row in tableview segues to a detail view with employee details. (This table view and detail view already exist as a standalone navigation menu option).
3. Now I need to add a button on the fly to the detail view to select specific employee, but only when called from alert button (ok).

---

```
// Code in alert
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Action Taken", message: scan.stringValue, preferredStyle: .alert)
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in gotoTableView()}))
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler:nil))
present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

func gotoTableView () {
    let Employee1TableViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewFromScanner")

    // the code below helped add searchbar to the table view. Witout this, the tableview didn't have search capability
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(Employee1TableViewController!, animated: true)
}
```

---

```
// Code in tableview that the alert calls, which in turn cals a Segue to detail screen
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: indexPath)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let rowSelected = (sender as! IndexPath).row
    if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? EmpViewController {
        destinationVC.empIdText = getSwiftArrayFromPlist()[rowSelected]["empid"]
        destinationVC.firstNameText = getSwiftArrayFromPlist()[rowSelected]["firstname"]
        destinationVC.lastNameText = getSwiftArrayFromPlist()[rowSelected]["lastname"]

    // code goes on further to list other employee details
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set a bool for this

```
 var currentCaller:Bool?

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let rowSelected = (sender as! IndexPath).row
    if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? EmpViewController {
        destinationVC.empIdText = getSwiftArrayFromPlist()[rowSelected]  
        destinationVC.calledFromAlert = self.currentCaller
     }
 }
```

OR

```
 let Employee1TableViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewFromScanner") as! Employee1TableViewController
Employee1TableViewController.calledFromAlert = true
```

Otherwise default is false

```
 class Employee1TableViewController:TableViewController
 {
   var calledFromAlert:Bool

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your update. I am not seeing calledFromAlert as a selection when I type . (dot) next to Employee1TableViewController or destinationVC. Is this something I should declare? How?

Comment: Thanks. I just added the variable to Employee1TableViewController. But I get a error "Value of type 'UIViewController?' has no member 'calledFromAlert' Just to let you know, this command is in the first view controller that calls Employee1TableViewController. I am also not seeing this as a selection when I type a dot next to destinationVC in Employee1TableViewController. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I think I am beginning to understand. the "as!" setting allowed me to set the boolean to true in the first view. On the third view, I set the other variable currentCaller as boolean. I think these things will allow me to see that the call came from alert. Now I need to work on creating a button that works only when the boolean is true. Thank you!